# List all packages installed with Guix

Tags: guix

How do I list all the packages installed through Guix? On Ubuntu this would be done through `dpkg -l`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
guix package --list-installed
```

to list all the installed packages. Throw on a `| grep name` at the end to search for "name" in that list.

Comment: No need for `grep`, you can match against a regex with `--list-installed=regex`.

Comment: Huh, unusual. The `guix` command is not able to take the argument value like `--list-installed regex` which I did try before writing.

Answer (score 5):

`guix package --list-installed` (`guix package -I`) is a valid answer to list the installed package on any linux distribution **by** the package manager`guix`.

But it is not the equivalent of `dpkg -l`. Why?

`dpkg -l` will list all the installed package on the system... `guix` isn't able to get information about the package installed through `apt`, `dpkg` ..., only the packages installed by the `guix` itself are accessed.

**On GuixSD**

GuixSD come with preinstalled packages; In addition of `guix package --list-installed`, to list the system wide package you need to set the `--profile` option:

```
guix package --list-installed --profile=/run/current-system/profile |awk '{print $1}'
```

e,g:

```
$ guix package --list-installed=zile
$
```

Dosn't return anything.

But:

```
$ guix package --list-installed --profile=/run/current-system/profile |awk '/zile/ {print $1,$2}'
zile 2.4.14
```

Package management (the emacs way):

- [3.1 Package Commands](https://emacs-guix.gitlab.io/website/manual/latest/html_node/Package-Commands.html)
- [4.1.1 Profile Commands](https://emacs-guix.gitlab.io/website/manual/latest/html_node/Profile-Commands.html#Profile-Commands)

Comment: Just for the record, another path to the system profile is `/var/guix/profiles/system/profile`, which I find easier to remember.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are correct about how to list the packages installed with `guix` in the user or the system profiles, but there are other packages which are installed to satisfy dependencies. Such packages are not listed by `guix package`, but they are installed in the store.

For comparison, `dpkg -l` lists all packages installed, whether they were installed specifically or automatically just to satisfy a dependency. I found myself looking for a similar list, first just for my general understanding, and later when I wanted to check that a driver package is present, even though I cannot tell by this whether such driver package is used.

Since all packages are installed to the store, one can look what directories are present in `/gnu/store` to determine which packages were installed. For myself, I came up with the following command, which finds directories immediately in `/gnu/store` with a dash in their names, then cuts away the part before the first dash, sorts them alphabetically, and removes duplicate entries. This is the closest to the list of installed packages that I could get so far.

```
$ find /gnu/store/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname '*-*' | cut -d '-' -f 2- | sort | uniq
```

Of course, this is a great feature of Guix to keep all of this hidden and allow the user to be concerned just with the packages shown by `guix package --list-installed`.

Comment: Thanks, keep safe.